# Can a google maps "pin" be HTML code rather than an image?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to display a custom pin on various location inside a map, but the problem is that the pins are very dynamic and keep changing on zoom in/out as well as some search parameters, So i was wondering if there is a way to create custom pins as Html code rather than an image.

For example what i want to do is

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: myLatLng,
   icon: // code here instead of a link to an image.
   map: map
});
```

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RichMarkers](https://github.com/googlearchive/js-rich-marker) to achieve this. This way you can render HTML styled with CSS as a map marker:

```
 marker = new RichMarker({
      position: mapCenter,
      map: map,
      draggable: true,
      content: '<div class="my-marker"><div>This is a nice image</div>' +
        '<div><img src="https://farm4.static.flickr.com/3212/3012579547_' +
        '097e27ced9_m.jpg"/></div><div>You should drag it!</div></div>'
      });
```

[image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/3d479df26b6d5b67238ffe2e9be288f9df4cf8d5/68747470733a2f2f676f6f676c656d6170732e6769746875622e696f2f6a732d726963682d6d61726b65722f73637265656e73686f742e6a7067]